# Sound Effect Identification and Text Pop Up Editing

Tags: after-effects, premiere, adobe

I watched this aviation video and I am trying to replicate the text pop-up exactly like this in Adobe Premier Pro when it says GROSSKOTZENBURG:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/26cbgpw235f2374/PilotsEye%20Sound%20Effect.mp4?dl=0

Specs are:

1. Background sound effect as soon as the text appears (if you could kindly help me identify what effect is used precisely, that would be much appreciated as I really like it)
2. Text appears to reveal itself in stages and moves as the video moves (if you could guide me to a youtube tutorial that perhaps covers the text motion side of things)
3. Text revelation itself (animation) - if you could point out a tutorial that covers this, would be highly appreciated

Apologies if my question isn't up to the standards of this forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound is three short 1kHz sine wave bursts with a gap between them. You could [generate this in Adobe Audition](https://helpx.adobe.com/audition/using/generate-tones-effect.html) or Audacity.

The effect looks like a 2D motion track in after effects, so the movement of the text tracks the movement of the landscape.  Before that there are two position and scale keyframes to make the text jump into position and out of position at the end.

All of this could be made with After Effects or Premiere. Here's a tutorial that explains both methods:

The font looks like [Helvetica Neue Extended Light](https://www.myfonts.com/products/pro-43-light-extended-189171-neue-helvetica-369559) according to [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/pages/whatthefont).

Comment: Wow! I love you man. Thank you for your time.
Can I buy you a coffee?